# Python string output on multiple line

Tags: python

I'm trying to create lengthy ip cmd to be executed on remote server but python breaks in 2 different line as a result it can't executed.

```
for line in result:
  ip_cmd="/sbin/ip -o -4 addr show %s scope global | awk '{print $4;}' | cut -d/ -f 1"%(line)
  print ip_cmd

Output
/sbin/ip -o -4 addr show eth0
 scope global | awk '{print $4;}' | cut -d/ -f 1
```

How can I get output on same line?

Thanks

Comment: instead of %(line) use %(line.rstrip()). This strips \n that seems to be causing the new line.

Comment: works! ..thanks for quick response:)